# Use Tinytest to test a Meteor app without making the app it into a package

Tags: testing, meteor

I know how to [use Tinytest to test a package](https://github.com/dandv/meteor-crypto-base64/blob/master/crypto-base64_tests.js), also how to [view its results on the console](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/N-XUxxra3iI/oDElfpzCsq8J) rather than in the webapp at `localhost:3000` but I'd like to [functionally test a Meteor app](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/BGvmpVObphs/3TZbh9p8eF0J) that's not really suitable to be made into a package. How can I do that? Or must I use [RTD](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/3QEhNXq2Rb4/iSNrfONamSEJ) or the new [Velocity](https://github.com/xolvio/velocity)?

Comment: Yes, I'd love an answer to this question as well. Of course, the canonical answer would be that you should split your Meteor app up into packages. The more pragmatic answer is that MDG writes modules for Meteor and not apps, so they don't really need to test apps. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben Green has published the [Tinytest In App](https://github.com/numtel/tinytest-in-app) Meteor package. It does not use Velocity, so you must clean up after yourself, but you avoid the [paradox of choice](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/rOvt3zsx2es/3qY03KspTi0J) and can get on with writing tests.

There's also a [numtel:velocity-tinytest](https://github.com/numtel/velocity-tinytest) package to use Velocity with Tinytest in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Dan — I think RTD is the best option at the moment — we're writing a book about testing meteor (http://testingmeteor.com/) and will likely develop our own approach in the course of that effort. In particular, we want a cucumber/gherkin layer for BDD that doesn't seem to exist yet.

Comment: Looks awesome! I'd upvote but I'm out of votes. BTW, typo on the website, "precised".

Comment: RTD supports cucumberjs and there's an example you can see here: https://github.com/xolvio/meteor-rtd-example-project/tree/master/test/features